# Proxy settings in Spring security saml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, proxy, spring-saml

I'm learning Spring security using SAML. I got the example from

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml

I'm in a network where I have proxy. So I hard to find this solution to enter proxy details. I used the following in `securityContext.xml`

```
<bean id="hostConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="hostConfiguration"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setProxy"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>proxyhost.com</value>
            <value>5555</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but still I'm getting connection refused error.

> Open connection to idp.ssocircle.com:80
>    Closing the connection.
>    I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
>   Connection refused: connect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)`

Pardon me if my understanding is wrong, sorry for wasted your time if it is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding something like the following snippet to your configuration:

```
<bean id="metadataManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg type="java.util.Timer" ref="metadataTimer"/>
                <constructor-arg type="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient" ref="samlHttpClient"/>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">${saml.idp.url}</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then you should create the samlHttpClient with any settings you like, i.e the proxy address.